# Reputation points wild fluctuations?

Tags: support, reputation

I noticed that my reputation points go through roller coaster rides from time to time. During the last couple of days, it widely fluctuated between 1025 and 1263. The main StackExchange [top users](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/44/week/cstheory)
web page is still showing that my reputation as 1263. Are our moderators aware of these irregularities? What is the reason for these wild reputation fluctuations?

Comment: I have noticed that this has happened three times to you. I can explain it if you can explain the sudden jumps in your [reputation](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/495?tab=reputationhistory).

Comment: I think the history chart indicates a fair amount of downvoting, which might explain parts of it

Comment: @Kaveh, If I had an explanation, I would not be asking the question here. Anyway, something strange is going on...

Comment: @moderators, Aren't the votes locked after one hour?

Comment: @Suresh, this morning my reputation was 1104. Now it is 1035. I did not get that many downvotes that explains a drop of 69 points (according to the link Jukka provided). Could you please check these irregularities?

Comment: not sure what locking is in this case ?

Comment: I think you might need to post on meta.stackoverflow about this. it might help to document the problem with some snapshots, and combine that with the reputation graph indicating that there's no explanation for this fluctuation.

Comment: @Suresh, Locking: when a user tries to change an upvote or a downvote (I think after one hour) the SE engine displays a message stating that the vote is locked and can't be changed.

Comment: i see. also, I don't think you're the only one with this problem (Sariel Har-Peled also appears to have rep fluctuation), so documenting the problems might help build a case

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68112/how-did-i-lose-1-000-points-in-a-day-on-so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something similar happened to me several days ago.  I had a sudden large jump in reputation, and the summary of recent activity showed what look like one person simultaneously upvoting every answer I had ever posted.  A day or two later it reverted to its original levels, and the reputation history showed no record of the surge ever happening.  Of course, it could be that the user just took back all his votes, but it seemed odd.

Comment: I think that there is a "suspicious voting" script that, when triggered, reverts all the recent votes, which would explain why a jump is then followed by a large loss in rep.

Comment: Ahh, that would explain it.

Comment: The exact same thing happened to me.

Comment: Does this mean that one should not upvote stuff by user?  I've several times looked at the contributions of someone who is about to hit a rep milestone, and often found several posts I had missed the first time around that deserved to be upvoted.  This generates several upvotes for the same person in quick succession.

Comment: Let us assume the existence of "suspicious voting" script. Many users experience sudden surges in their reputation. Why is the script selectively targets only some of those users?

Comment: I am sure I heard mention of such a script somewhere, though I'm not sure where. It may have been one of the podcasts. A quick search on meta.stackoverflow.com yields a bunch of posts mentioning one.

Comment: @turkistany: It's probably set off by specific events, like one person making many votes for a particular user's posts in a short period of time.  Votes by many different people, votes in response to new posts, etc. are probably ok.

Comment: @Andras: I think if you do that you should spread it out over a long period of time.  I had another such jump in reputation yesterday, going from 940 to over 1000 and crossing a reputation milestone seemingly due to one user, and it has since been wiped out.

Comment: @turkistany: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68112/how-did-i-lose-1-000-points-in-a-day-on-so for related problems.

Comment: @Ian @Andras: I agree with Ian.  Someone sent me over 1500 yesterday, and I'm back under 1500 this morning.  This may have happened before, I don't know, but I noticed it this time because the system gave me more privileges and then removed them.

Answer (score 3):

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: thanks for your help. But the link did not explain the extreme fluctuations.

Comment: If your *current* total reputation (as displayed on your own user page) is *approximately* equal to the reputation shown in the above link, then everything should be ok now.

Comment: also, the above link, seen  from your profile, details every single click that changes your reputation.